Finiteness of non-orientable 3-manifolds with the same orientable two-fold cover
Given a compact, orientable and boundary incompressible 3-manifold $M$. Suppose that either $M$ is closed, or $\partial M$ consists of tori.
For which non-orientable 3-manifolds $N$, the orientable two-fold cover of $N$ is homeomorphic to $M$? In particular, are there only finitely many homeomorphism types of such $N$?

For $M$ irreducible (Haken), the result of Zimmermann (Theorem 4.1 & Corollary 4.2)  implies the finiteness. I'm not sure about reducible $M$.

Zimmerman's theorem can certainly be extended to the non-Haken (but still irreducible) closed case: see Theorem 5.1 here https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.2101 .

I do not understand the question "for which..." Are you asking for an algorithm? As for finiteness, it mostly follows from the existence of "prime decomposition" of such nonorientable manifolds. Just check that there are only finitely many homeomorphism types of possible prime factors of such manifolds $N$. There is a slight difficulty with 2-sided projective planes in such $N$'s (you have to split along those ones too), you have to work with orbifolds to handle these. But Zimmerman's finiteness theorem still applies even if the group action is not free.
